# Automatically use specific language in Notepad++ for files with no extension

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, vagrant

Specifically, I want NPP to remember to use Ruby syntax highlighting whenever I open a Vagrantfile. These don't have an extension, and I tried adding "Vagrantfile" to the user extensions in the style configurator, but it did not work.

Anyone get this working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786906/how-to-associate-languages-with-files-without-extensions-in-notepad/

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin which can detect the language based on [vi modelines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) and [shebangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) etc.:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonplugsq/files/Modeline%20Parser/

> This Notepad++ plugin will read Vim modeline to have per file settings. It also supports shebang (#!) to select language.

You need to install the Python Script plugin from the plugin manager, and manually install ModelineParser_0.2.zip.  If needed it may be possible to add your own custom recognition strings.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268995/225906)

Answer (score 2):

You should add the extension of your vagrantfile, e.g. pkg, not the word "vagrantfile" itself!

In Notepad++, go to Settings -> Style Configurator. From the language list on the far left, choose Ruby. Below that there is a field titled User ext. Write in it all the file extensions, seperated by spaces, that you want to be treated as Ruby.

Comment: `Vagrantfile` has no extension. That's the problem.